# The minimum number of independent axioms of a theory?

Tags: logic, axioms

Suppose a theory is based on $N$ independent axioms. My [intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200849/is-there-a-meaningful-analogy-between-axiomatic-systems-and-vector-spaces?noredirect=1#comment6586644_3200849) was that any $N$ independent theorems of this theory could be chosen as the axioms, constructing the same theory. I'd like to know if it's true, but the more important question to me: Is it possible to obtain the same theory (or a broader theory containing all theorems of that theory) by less than $N$ axioms? The motivation for this question comes from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476162/what-would-be-the-mathematical-features-of-a-theory-of-everything?noredirect=1#comment1069598_476162).

Edit: I understand your objections, and I agree that different numbers could be assigned to the same set of axioms. So there's no measure of brevity or irreducibility for basis of an axiomatic system?

Comment: You can always "and" the axioms together, to get one axiom. You might want to exclude conjunctions from the top level of your axioms.

Comment: It sounds like you think of axioms as if they were the basis of a vector space, but there's no analogous same-cardinality result for choices of axioms for a theory. (How are you counting them, by the way? For example, do you count an axiom schema once or $\aleph_0$ times?)

Comment: Conjunctions can be reproduced by disjunctions and negations, and you can have a theory with no axioms at all, but with many inference rules. This question only makes sense in artificial systems where everything is reduced to literals, for example, as in [resolution systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) with a single inference rule. And many interesting theories (including Peano arithmetic) need [axiom schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema), so the number must be infinite.

Comment: There is no notion of basis of an axiomatic system for the first. You can ask if there is a finite axiomatization of a theory, but even this has some strange properties: for example, you ZFC can't be axiomatized in finite number of axioms, but it's conservative extension NBG can.

Comment: @J.G. cardinality of a theory is well defined term, about schema axioms, you first check the outer cardinality of all formulas in the language, then this is the cardinality of the scheme axiom.

Comment: I suspect the answer to the physics question that you reference is that the OP there is indeed confused about the nature of formal systems and how formal systems are applied in physics.